# How to set gulp.dest() outside the parent folder

Tags: gulp

I am setting up a new web application in netbeans. It has the following directory structure.

```
project
├── gulpfile.js
├── package.json
├── Sources
│    └── public
│         └── js
|              └──main.js
└── Site Root
      └── js
```

In my gulpfile.js I have

```
// Concatenate & Minify JS
gulp.task('scripts', function() {
return gulp.src('public/js/*.js')
  .pipe(concat('main.js'))
    .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('../Site Root/js'));

});
```

This runs but creates Site Root in the Sources folder so

```
project
 ├── gulpfile.js
 ├── package.json
 ├── Sources
 │  └── Site Root
 |      └──js
 |      |     └──main.min.js
 │      └── public
 │         └── js
 |              └──main.js
 └── Site Root
       └── js
```

How do I configure the task so that it puts the output into the Site Root folder.

Answer (score 2):

It's because of gulp.src is set to public/js.
when you are running task you gulp.dest is taking public/js as your current path.

try this :

```
 .pipe(gulp.dest('../../Site Root/js'));
```

Comment: This gives Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/dist' even if I create t

Comment: try to run it in sudo mode. sudo gulp<your command> @user3617712